# Is that possible to set log level to DEBUG on running Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a running Jupiter-notebook. It has been working for a long time (about 6 hours). I am curious about it was still alive or died. There is no error massage or interrupting notification. In activity monitor, Python is using the most of the memory and CPU. I need to see its detailed logs but at the beginning I did not start notebook in debug level. Is that possible to check the notebook still alive or set the log level to debug?